# database rollback from the command line throwing exception liquibase

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I am trying to use liquibase to roll back to previous sql I executed from the command prompt which runs sucessfully but when I try to rollback to previous state of the database I get an error. This is my attempt

```
liquibase rollbackCountSql 1 --changeLogFile=src/main/resources/liquibase/db.changelog.xml --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookstore"
```

Please what is my wrong. Kindly assist!

Comment: What was the error message?

Comment: @SteveDonie Errors: Url is required chanlog is required

Comment: Try changing the order of things on the command line - the options need to come before the command.

liquibase --changeLogFile=src/main/resources/liquibase/db.changelog.xml --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookstore" rollbackCountSql 1

Comment: unexpected error running liquibase cannot run base driver

Comment: Could you just copy and paste the error? That message doesn't sound like it has all the details.